# supplying custom knot values to geom_smooth() by facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm trying to plot some piecewise/broken-stick regressions using geom_smooth. For example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, 
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 2, degree = 1, knots = 20)) +
  facet_wrap(~gear)
```

[image: piecewise regression by facet]

However this uses a single value (knots=20) for the breakpoint in each facet. I would like to pass a unique value for each facet (that I have calculated earlier). Is this possible?

I tried adding a variable to the data frame and passing the variable name (e..g, `psi`) as an aesthetic, but geom_smooth wouldn't recognize it. I suspect the answer has something to do with defining a custom function as described at the end of this page: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html

Thankyou so much for considering my problem.

Best,

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a tricky problem. One solution is to use a separate `geom_smooth` for each `gear` by filtering the data and supplying the corresponding value for `knots`.

In this example it's assumed that knots = gear * 4.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mtcars, gear == 3),
              method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 2, degree = 1, knots = 12)) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mtcars, gear == 4),
              method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 2, degree = 1, knots = 16)) +
  geom_smooth(data = filter(mtcars, gear == 5),
              method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, df = 2, degree = 1, knots = 20)) +
  facet_wrap(~gear)
```

Result:

[image]